# The isomorphism $F \simeq h_C(X)$ determines $X$ how?

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

I've asked something similar before, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398668/representability-h-cx-simeq-f-of-functors-determines-rep-x-up-to-unique).  But I didn't quite understand their reasoning.  So I'm breaking the problem down.  First of all, how is $X$ *determined*?

By yoneda $\text{Hom}_{C^{\wedge}}(h_C(X), F) \simeq F(X)$ so if there is a natural isomorphism $h_C(X) \simeq F$, then ?

I'm sorry!  I just don't understand how you get back to $X$ from this.

---

**EDIT**.  If $h_C(X) \simeq F \simeq h_C(Y)$ then there exists an isomorphism between $h_C(X)$ and $h_C(Y)$ which is induced by $s \in h_C(X,Y)$ by the Yoneda bijection $\psi(s)$.  The inverse bijection is $\varphi$ and if $\theta : h_C(X) \to h_C(Y)$ is an isomorphism then since $h_C$ is fully faithful, it reflects isomorphisms, so $\phi(\theta) = s' \in \text{Hom}_C(X,Y)$ is an isomorphism.

So $s

Comment: @DerekElkins I don't know about skolemization yet.  I want to say that yes $X$ represents $F$, and if $X'$ also represents $F$ then $X \simeq X'$ uniquely.

Comment: That follows immediately from Yoneda's lemma

Comment: @EyesOnBud As Mariano Suárez-Álvarez says, that statement is a ubiquitously used corollary of Yoneda and the argument in your edit is a reasonable proof sketch. I recommend working out the details and getting explicit formulas for everything since this is a fundamental result.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thanks.  Working on it :)